# Calculate Wh from power logger data set

Tags: power

I have a silly question which has got me confused. I've collected some data from a device I've designed to characterize the power usage in various modes. I used a power logger to log the power profile over a use session of about 400 seconds. I have this data as a log file with TIME and POWER columns. When plotted, the data looks something like the attached image (sorry for the analogue method).

How can I calculate the Wh power draw from the battery from this data?

I'm thinking to import data into python, then use a numerical integration to obtain the area under the power curve, and then what? Am I on the right track at all?

Thank you! 
[image: Power Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct. If you are sampling, for example, every 5 s then take each reading, multiply by it by 5 to give you the number of Ws (watt-seconds) add them all up and divide by 3600 (seconds in an hour) to get Wh.

> What happens if the sampling is not at a constant rate? My sampling rate varies a bit between 1 and 2s.

As long as you know the individual *dt* between readings you can work out the watt-seconds as before (using *dt* rather than '5').

You might improve the accuracy by using the *average* power for each period.

```
#    t      Power   Period average (W)   dt (s)   Energy (Ws)
0    0.0    0.31    -                    -        -
1    1.2    0.36    (0.31 + 0.36) / 2    1.2      0.402
2    3.0    0.40    (0.36 + 0.40) / 2    1.8      0.684
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you just please clarify what happens if the sampling is not at a constant rate. My sampling rate varies a bit between 1 and 2s. I suppose python's numerical integration (eg trapezoidal method) will take care of that if I give it both the time and power arrays? i.e. it will figure out each dt individually from the TIME series?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Python numerical integration but as long as you have accurate timestamps or intervals you will be able to calculate. See updated answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm still not sure this is correct. If we integrate the power over the time the dataset was taken (let's say 10.3 seconds), then I think we don't get Ws, we get watts consumed over 10.3s. Hence we first need to divide the integral of power by 10.3s to get (average) Ws, and then divide by 3600 to get Wh. Does that make sense? This would mean the answer above is incorrect, as it does not divide by the total time the dataset was taken (eg 10.3 secs) before dividing by 3600 to get Wh?

Comment: The sanity check is to check what happens the units. (1) The integral is the area under the curve. Your vertical axis is marked 'W' and the horizontal is 's'. The area must be 'Ws'. This is energy and not power. (2) If you divide the integral by 10.3 you get Ws/s = W. That gives you the average P. Multiply the average by the time (10.3) to get the total Ws just brings you back to where you started. (Think about it. It would, wouldn't it!)

Comment: (3) Let's say we measured a continuous 3 W output for 1h: integral = 3 W x 3600 s = 10,800 Ws. Divide by 3600 s/h and we get 3 Wh. (4) Now let's say we got 3 W for 30 minutes and 0 W for 30 minutes: integral = 3 W x 1800 s = 5,400 Ws. Divide that by 3,600 s/h and we get 1.5 Wh. Does that all make sense?

Comment: Hi Transistor, yep it's all clear now! Thanks a lot!